# Check duplicate's before inserting data in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Im inserting 3 values into a database on a click of a button, 1 is the insert date, 2 is a number from a editText and the 3rd is the value assigned to the button being clicked(there are six different buttons that can be clicked)

What I want to do is check if the date and number are already in the database the 3rd value does not matter. I cant use unique on any of the columns as I want the number from the editText to be able to be entered again but just not on the same day.

I have got this far...
and it does not enter any data to database

From MainActivity

```
    public void onClick_30(View v) {

    counter++;
    cnt_bcs30++;

    String getCowNum = CowNum.getText().toString();

    Cursor C = myDB.dubUpCheck();
    String ddate = C.getString(DBAdapter.COL_DATE);
    String cow = C.getString(DBAdapter.COL_COW);


    if(C.moveToFirst()){

        do {

            if(ddate == dateFormat.format(date) && cow == getCowNum){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getCowNum + "Has already been scored today ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }while (C.moveToNext());


    }else{



    myDB.insertRow(dateFormat.format(date), getCowNum, 3.0);

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getCowNum + " " + score30,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    CowNum.clearFocus();
    }
}
```

From my DBAdapter

```
            public Cursor dubUpCheck() {

    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String []{KEY_DATE, KEY_COW}, null, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }

    return c;

}
```

I need to check if there is a row with dateFormat.format(date) and getCowNum but i cant seem to get it to work, not sure if it is due to the way I am storing the date which is a string in the format of dd-MM-yyyy

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
```

like this, enters data but still allows dupicates

```
    public void onClick_30(View v) {

    counter++;
    cnt_bcs30++;

    String getCowNum = CowNum.getText().toString();

    Cursor C = myDB.dubUpCheck();
    String ddate = C.getString(DBAdapter.COL_DATE);
    String cow = C.getString(DBAdapter.COL_COW);


    if(ddate == dateFormat.format(date) && cow == getCowNum){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getCowNum + "Has already been scored today ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{



    myDB.insertRow(dateFormat.format(date), getCowNum, 3.0);

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getCowNum + " " + score30,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    CowNum.clearFocus();
    }
```

UPD: Another attempt... the else statement is in the wrong place I know but thats not all thats wrong Im guessing

```
        public void onClick_30(View v) {

    counter++;
    cnt_bcs30++;

    String getCowNum = CowNum.getText().toString();

    Cursor C = myDB.dubUpCheck();
    String ddate = C.getString(DBAdapter.COL_DATE);
    String cow = C.getString(DBAdapter.COL_COW);

    if (C.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if (ddate.equals(dateFormat.format(date)) && cow.equals(getCowNum)) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        getCowNum + "Has already been scored today ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        } while (C.moveToNext());
    } else {

        myDB.insertRow(dateFormat.format(date), getCowNum, 3.0);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getCowNum + " " + score30,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        CowNum.clearFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can store the time in the form of milliseconds and then put a unique constraint on the same.it will solve your problem

Comment: You can create a UNIQUE constraint with two columns.

Comment: Why aren't you using one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime)?

Comment: Ok I am very new to JAVA and android development, I used that date format as it was the only one I could get to work due to lack of knowledge.

Comment: How would I go about putting a UNIQUE constraint on two columns?

Comment: Would it be like this CREATE TABLE tablename (row1 text, row2 text, row3 text UNIQUE(row1, row2)");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just a simple `WHERE`?

```
/** @return true if given date/cowNum combination is already in the db, false otherwise */
public boolean dubUpCheck(Date date, String cowNum) {
  /* The 3rd parameter is treated as SQL WHERE clause, ? are replaced by strings
   * from the 4th parameter */
  Cursor cur = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, "DATE = ? AND COW_NUM = ?", new String[] {dateFormat.format(date), getCowNum}, null, null, null, null);
  if (cur != null && cur.getCount()>0) {
      // duplicate found
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

**UPD**
In your approach where you manually compare strings you've made a classic Java rookie mistake. You're comparing `String` objects using the operator `==` : it will return `false` for different [in terms of instances] objects that might actually be identical content-wise (e.g. this `"foo" == new String("foo")` will give you `false`). You have to use `.equals()` like so:

```
ddate.equals(dateFormat.format(date)) && cow.equals(getCowNum)
```

But really, try the approach above, it creates less objects and will spare you all the string comparison stuff.

*It seems you could benefit from reading a good book on Java -- e.g. [Thinking in Java by Bruce Eckel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872486) is hands down one of the most awesome reads for both novice and intermediate Java devs*

Comment: If put this code into my mainactivity, would I then have to create a method in my dbadapter? I am very new to all this so baby steps please.

Comment: @BaSSa Well you already have the method -- the dubUpCheck (although I don't really get why it's return type is `Cursor` not `boolean`). This code is meant as the body of your method. If the condition is true -- there's a duplicate already present in your db. If it's not -- there isn't.

Comment: Check out the updated answer, I've put the code in context for more clarity on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ivan although I kind of understand what the code is trying to do I cant seem to implement it, think my lack of knowledge is the problem, I have been trying other way to do this(see edited question) but still no luck

Comment: I get multiple errors trying to use your code, lets start with line 1,
 Multiple markers at this line
 - Illegal modifier for parameter dubUpCheck; only final is 
  permitted
 - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected

And if i try to use `ddate.equals(dateFormat.format(date)) && cow.equals(getCowNum)` it returns false and inserts duplicates

Comment: _> equals_ ok then they must be different, use debugger to check the values there, there must be an error somewhere else (like maybe you haven't called `moveToNext()` on your cursor before reading values from it, so it's on the position before the first element). _>multiple errors_ the markers you described suggest you're trying to use the method I wrote as a parameter to something, don't do that.

Comment: ok you are right on both, I have not called `moveToNext()` and have no clue how to implement it in my code, I tried with a `do while`(See update question) but thats wrong, the `else` is not going to run.
If I use your method in my dbadapter.java the issues is these `dateFormat.format(date), getCowNum` are defined in my main activity

Comment: well, that's what method parameters are for, you call the method and pass the date and `getCowNum`. Actually, it'll be simpler if you replace the `Date` param type with `String` and remove the formatting call in my code above -- and format the date into `String` in your main activity, pass as a string not a date, so that DBHelper doesn't need to create the formatter.